# Add toggle Button on another Button

Tags: android, xml, android-togglebutton

I am working on the Android Application in which i have to implement the Customized `Toggle Button` on the `Button` and if the user click on the `Button` than toggle button perfrom ON/OFF respectively.
check image for reference:
[image]

Here is Button Code:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/textViewBackground"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
           >

        </Button>
```

---

### Edit :

Full view:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardView_top_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardView_bottom_margin"
        android:id="@+id/cardView9"
        >

        <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/textview"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:background="@color/textViewBackground"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView8"
                    android:gravity="start|center"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/inner_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/inner_margin"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon">
        </Button>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" />
```

toggle_selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on"
android:state_checked="true"/>

   <item
android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off"
android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

in code:

```
 toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                text.setText("Status: " + isChecked);
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: how can i implement on the button

Comment: why not using a `ToggleButton` instead of button?

Comment: actualy if the click on the Background Button/TextView , than toggle button is respond.. for eg in `lollipop` when we click on the Wifi option

Answer (score 0):

Create clickable View with Button drawable as background that contains ImageView and TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"
         /> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add toggle function to onclick of relative view working as a button

Comment: i added my full view can u add the Toggle button on my upper view

Comment: @DhruvTyagi replace button with my layout and make necessary changes

Comment: or even use the views i have added inside Relative layout inside the cardview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` layout to achieve this

Refer this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Arjun-sna/7be4fcbcb38bc32650906f364c0869f5)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding vertical Layout with weight

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textViewBackground"
        android:id="@+id/cardView9"
        >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/textview"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:background="@color/textViewBackground"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardView8"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/inner_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/inner_margin"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
            >

        </Button>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggBtn"
        android:gravity="end|center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end|right"
        android:background="@drawable/toglle_button_background"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
           />

</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```